# Want to find number of active buttons in a page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find the number of active buttons on a page when user clicks on a "CONTINUE" button.

There are 10 buttons in the page which has the class "btnp"

```
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>//10 buttons are there in the page
```

Code for continue button:

```
<button type="button" class="continue-btn nextStepButton">
    Continue <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
```

For that I am using the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var gcnt = 0;
      $('.continue-btn').click(function(){
        getCnt( $( "btnp" ).toArray());//btnp is a class
        function getCnt( btng ) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < btng.length; i++ )
            {
                if ( $( btng[i] ).hasClass( "active" ) )
                {
                    gcnt= gcnt+1;
                }
            }
            console.log(gcnt);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please help anyone.

Comment: Or tell me how to pass a class name as an argument to a jquery function?

Answer (score 3):

Your JS logic is very over-complicated. You can simply select the buttons with the `active` class and get the `length` from the returned jQuery object.

```js
$('.btnp').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('.continue-btn').click(function() {
  var activeCount = $('.btnp.active').length;
  console.log(activeCount);
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>
<button class="btnp">SELECT</button>

<br /><br />

<button type="button" class="continue-btn nextStepButton">
  Continue <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Very very thank you for your help.I got it. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, glad to help